# Location of function call changes functionality

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

When writing to a GPIO output register (BCM2711 chip on the Raspberry Pi 4), the location of my `clear_register` function call changes the result completely. The code is below.

```
void clear_register(long reg) {

    *(unsigned int*)reg = (unsigned int)0;

}

int set_pin(unsigned int pin_number) {

    long reg = SET_BASE; //0xFE200001c

    clear_register(SET_BASE);

    unsigned int curval = *(unsigned int*)reg;
    unsigned int value = (1 << pin_number);

    value |= curval;

    gpio_write(reg, value);
    return 1;
}
```

When written like this, the register gets cleared. However, if I call `clear_register(SET_BASE)` *before* `long reg = SET_BASE`, the registers don't get cleared. I can't tell why this would make a difference; any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the size of `long`? `0xFE200001c` may be overflowing, and you should use `unsigned long`.

Comment: Symptoms like this are almost always the result of undefined behavior somewhere in the code.

Comment: Why not use proper pointers to begin with? As in `unsigned int * const reg = (unsigned int *) SET_BASE;`? Still not very good, but at least better than the possible signed `long` problem you might have now.

Comment: @Bamar I meant *before. I've edited the post. I'm running the Pi in 64 bit mode, so the long should also be 64 bits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had it set like that before. However, it didn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Also for the `clear_register` argument?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I passed a pointer argument instead.

Comment: Are you intentionally mixing 8-byte signed `long` and 4-byte `unsigned`? `SET_BASE` wont fit in `unsigned int curval` regardless of cast to pointer and dereference. (what you get is some random 4-byte value at address `0xFE200001c`. Is that indented?

Comment: Put a printf() in clear_register() to see the actual value received by the function.

Comment: Not sure if this is your immediate problem, but since your `*(unsigned int *)reg` is not `volatile`, the compiler can optimize out the reload, assuming it still equals the 0 that you stored.  See https://godbolt.org/z/6xz1PhvMW . Since it appears to be a memory-mapped hardware register, I am guessing that is not what you want.  However, for me that happens regardless of how the code is rearranged.

Comment: @nateeldredge it didn't solve this problem but it will solve one in the future I'm sure. I'll change my casts to ```volatile``` thanks

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce it since I don't have the target hardware which allows writing to that address but you have several bugs and dangerous style issues:

- `0xF E2 00 00 1c` (64 bit signed) does not necessarily fit inside a `long` (possibly 32 bit) and certainly does not fit inside a `unsigned int` (16 or 32 bits).
- Even if that was a typo and you meant to write `0xFE20001c` (32 bit), your program still stuffers from "sloppy typing", which is when the programmer just type out `long`, `int` etc without given it any deeper thought. The outcome is strange, subtle and intermittent bugs. I think everyone can relate to the situation "just cast it to unsigned int and it works" but you have no idea why. Bugs like that are always caused by "sloppy typing".

  You should be using the `stdint.h` types instead. `uint32_t` and so on.
- Also related to "sloppy typing", there exist very few cases where you want to actually use signed numbers in embedded systems - certainly not when dealing with addresses and bits. Negative addresses in Linux is a thing - kernel space - but accidentally changing an address to a negative value is a bug.

  Signed types will only cause problems when doing bitwise arithmetic and they come with overflows. So you need to nuke the presence of every signed variable in your code unless it explicitly needs to be signed.

  This means no sloppy `long` but the correct type, which is either `uint32_t` or `uintptr_t` if it should hold an address, as is the case in your example. It also mean so sloppy hex constants, they must *always* have `u` suffix: `0xFE20001Cu` or they easily boil down to the wrong type.

  For these reasons `1 <<`  is always a bug in a C program, because `1` is of type signed `int` and you may end up shifting into the sign bit of that signed int, which is undefined behavior. There exists no reason why you shouldn't write `1u <<` , always.
- Whenever you are dealing with hardware registers, you must always use `volatile` qualified pointers or you might end up with very strange bugs caused by the optimizer. No exceptions here either.
- `(unsigned int)0` is a pointless cast. If you wish to be explict you could write `0u` but that doesn't change anything in case of assignment, since a "lvalue conversion" to the type of the left operand always happens upon assignment. `0u` does make some static analysers happy though, MISRA C checkers etc.

With all bug fixes, your clear function should for example look something like this:

```
void clear_register (uintptr_t reg) {
    *(volatile uint32_t*)reg = 0;
}
```

Or better yet, don't write functions for such very basic things! `*(volatile uint32_t*)SET_BASE = 0;` is perfectly clear, readable and self-documented code. While `clear_register(SET_BASE)` suggests that something more advanced than just a simple write is taking place.

However, you could have placed the cast inside the `SET_BASE` macro. For details and examples see [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you're saying. However, most of those things I had written originally with the same bug, so my code has been updated as an attempt to be very clear about what's wrong. For example, I hadn't originally cast ```(unsigned int)0```. All of my long types are indeed 64 bits because I made sure of that when setting up and writing my basic kernel. I understand the benefits of using the stdint.h library, but I'm writing specifically for my platform, so that's not the problem as I'm sure of my type sizes. I agree I should be using the volatile keyword and I've updated my code.

Comment: However, I didn't know about the hex constants and the or think about specifically using "1" as unsigned when doing manipulations such as ```1 <<``` so I appreciate the feedback there. This is my first time writing to hardware registers so I know I have a lot to learn! I'll look into these suggestions thank you